# Why is pygame.key.get_pressed not working as expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

The `pygame.key.get_pressed()` function seems not to be working as expected on my Mac OSX (10.11.1) using Python 3 and Pygame.

After importing `pygame` and the `time` module I check if the <kbd>w</kbd> key (`pygame.K_w`) is pressed by using a simple `if`-statement and Pygames `pygame.key.get_pressed()` function.

But the test fails and `It didn't work` is printed very time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pygame, time
pygame.init()

while True:
    keypressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    time.sleep(5)
    print("5 seconds later")

    if keypressed[pygame.K_w]:
         print("it worked")
    else: 
         print("It didn't work")
```

Comment: how is it not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that **you don´t actually create a Pygame window**. **Use the [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) function to initialize a window** or screen for displaying. Normally this is done before calling the main event loop in a Pygame program:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

#initialize a display with 100 x 100 pix resolution  
display = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))

while True:
    #some code
```

Because you are not using any event functions in your main game loop, **Pygame can not handle internal actions**, such as key state information information. To avoid this **you should call [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump)** inside the event loop:

```
while True:
    #internally process pygame event handlers
    pygame.event.pump()
    keypressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    time.sleep(5)
    print("5 seconds later")

    if keypressed[pygame.K_w]:
        print("it worked")
    else: 
        print("It didn't work")
```

Now your program should recognize `pygame.K_w` key actions, but only every 5 seconds since you sleep the game using Pythons `time.sleep()` function.

Because this isn't really a good practice there are a number of solutions to avoid this problem. You could:

- **call instead of the `pygame.event.pump()` function [`pygame.event.wait()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.wait) to wait for an event** and sleep the game when no events are happening:

  ```
  import pygame
  pygame.init()

  display = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))

  while True:
      #wait for a single event from the queue
      pygame.event.wait()
      keypressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

      if keypressed[pygame.K_w]:
          print("it worked")
      else: 
          print("It didn't work")
  ```
- **use a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object to set a framerate** for your program:

  ```
  import pygame
  pygame.init()

  display = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))

  clock = pygame.time.Clock()

  while True:
      pygame.event.pump()
      keypressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

      if keypressed[pygame.K_w]:
          print("it worked")
      else: 
          print("It didn't work")

      #compute how many milliseconds have passed since the previous call
      clock.tick(30)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should initialize your pygame window, then call your function that will process all your events (like waiting for a key to get pressed and reacting to it after that).

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screensize = (100, 100) #choose the size, in pixels.
window = pygame.display.set_mode(screensize) #Initialize your pygame window!
gameloop()
```

Your game loop is a function that looks like this:

```
while not finished:
    finished = doStuff() #returns True if the game should end.
pygame.quit()
```

The variable 'finished' is supposed to let the program know when it is supposed to end, for example, after pressing the 'X' in the top-right corner of the window.
Inside this function, we will listen to all the events, such as pressing a Key, releasing it, holding it and so on.

```
def doStuff():
    events = pygame.event.get() #Use this function to get all the events that happened, then iterate through it.
    finished = False
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_w:
            print("It worked!")
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            final = True
        else:
            print("It didn't work")
        #more events here
    return finished
```